# What does Betrand Russell mean when he says the mathematicians refuted the philosophers on the existence of infinity?

Tags: math-history, infinity, philosophy

In the second-to-last chapter of his book "The Problems of Philosophy", Bertrand Russell writes that philosophers used to think that there can't be such a thing as infinity, but they were disproved by Georg Cantor. Here is the exact quote:

> Most of the great ambitious attempts of metaphysicians have proceeded
>   by the attempt to prove that such and such apparent features of the
>   actual world were self-contradictory, and therefore could not be real.
>   The whole tendency of modern thought, however, is more and more in the
>   direction of showing that the supposed contradictions were illusory,
>   and that very little can be proved *a priori* from considerations of
>   what *must* be. A good illustration of this is afforded by space and
>   time. Space and time appear to be infinite in extent, and infinitely
>   divisible. If we travel along a straight line in either direction, it
>   is difficult to believe that we shall finally reach a last point,
>   beyond which there is nothing, not even empty space. Similarly, if in
>   imagination we travel backwards or forwards in time, it is difficult
>   to believe that we shall reach a first or last time, with not even
>   empty time beyond it. Thus space and time appear to be infinite in
>   extent.
>
> Again, if we take any two points on a line, it seems evident that
>   there must be other points between them, however small the distance
>   between them may be: every distance can be halved, and the halves can
>   be halved again, and so on *ad infinitum*. In time, similarly, however
>   little time may elapse between two moments, it seems evident that
>   there will be other moments between them. Thus space and time appear
>   to be infinitely divisible. But as against these apparent facts
>   infinite extent and infinite divisibility philosophers have advanced
>   arguments tending to show that there could be no infinite collections
>   of things, and that therefore the number of points in space, or of
>   instants in time, must be finite. Thus a contradiction emerged between
>   the apparent nature of space and time and the supposed impossibility
>   of infinite collections.
>
> Kant, who first emphasized this contradiction, deduced the
>   impossibility of space and time, which he declared to be merely
>   subjective; and since his time very many philosophers have believed
>   that space and time are mere appearance, not characteristic of the
>   world as it really is. Now, however, owing to the labours of the
>   mathematicians, notably Georg Cantor, it has appeared that the
>   impossibility of infinite collections was a mistake. They are not in
>   fact self-contradictory, but only contradictory of certain rather
>   obstinate mental prejudices. Hence the reasons for regarding space and
>   time as unreal have become inoperative, and one of the great sources
>   of metaphysical constructions is dried up. [The Problems of Philosophy, Chapter 14]

What Russell seems to be saying is that Kant based his theory of transcendental idealism on the idea that in reality there can't be such a thing as infinity. But along came Georg Cantor and proved that the whole thing was a mistake and that there can indeed be such a thing as infinity. (This is perhaps how Russell justifies his attack on Kant in Chapter 8.)

But my question is as follows. It seems to me that when mathematicians speak of infinity and when philosophers speak of infinity they are talking about different things. When a philosopher says there is no such thing as infinity, she means to say that in the real world there cannot be an infinite supply of things, be it cars, atoms, space or time. As many as you have you will never have infinity.

On the other hand, when a mathematician talks about infinity existing, she means abstractly. There is an abstract mathematical concept of infinity that we can talk about in math and it can have implications in theory. But it doesn't (and can't) actually exist.

So what is Bertrand Russell referring to? Am I wrong about mathematicians agreeing that infinity doesn't actually exist? I'm not familiar with the works of Georg Cantor, but how can he [Cantor] possibly prove such a thing?

Comment: I suggest that you ask this on the philosophy stackexchange, since mathematicians tend not to be very well-versed in philosophy, as  evidenced by quasi's answer.

Comment: Perhaps Russell means that earlier philosophers had claimed that infinity was a _logical_ impossibility. This was surely refuted by Cantor's set theory.

Comment: Also: one must be careful in philosophical discussions that one does not make unnecessary ontological commitments by reading ontology from certain linguistic practices. This is precisely what Russell was arguing against in his paper On Denoting; in this paper he developed a theory of denoting so that one could speak meaningfully without creating a bloated, extravagant ontology. This is especially relevant to mathematical discourse. When we make existential claims in mathematics, it doesn't seem that we are making ontological commitments to the existence of certain abstract objects.

Comment: How does "philosophy" relate to real-world existence? If by existence, Russell means physical existence in the real world, I think "physics" is the more the appropriate venue for such a question.

Comment: existence is overrated... Russell is also overrated.

Comment: @Masacroso Absolutely not! Russell was brilliant! A very influential philosopher.

Comment: @EliBashwinger Many mathematicians may not be well versed in philosophy, but do you think many philosophers are well versed in mathematics?

Comment: @wgrenard It depends upon the philosopher and the area of his/her specialization. For instance, Alexander Pruss, whom I mentioned below, has a PhD in philosophy AND mathematics. Hans Halverson is another philosopher who knows mathematics: he applies Category theory to logic and has done work in mathematical physics.

Comment: @wgrenard I see that you are student at UC Berkeley. I suggest that you go see Professor Paolo Mancosu in the philosophy department. He is a philosopher of mathematics.

Comment: @EliBashwinger Thanks for the recommendation :)

Comment: Maybe useful to go to "the orgins" (we hardly find a metaphysical tract of R); *Problems* was written in 1912 and the most complete R's philosophical work is still [Principles](https://books.google.it/books?id=SNWLAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (1903). See e.g. **Ch.43 THE PHILOSOPHY OF THE INFINITE**, page 360-on: "Let us first recapitulate briefly the positive theory of the infinite to which we have been led. Accepting as indefinable the notion proposition and the notion constituent of a proposition,[...] thus every propositional function defines a class." ...

Comment: "The above definition of a cardinal number, it should be observed, is based upon the notion of propositional functions, and nowhere involves enumeration;[...] In this way, starting from $0$, we obtain a progression of numbers, since any number $n$ leads to a new number $n + 1$. The progression so defined is the series of *finite* numbers. But there is no reason to think that all numbers can be so obtained; [...] A
number not belonging to this progression is called *infinite*. [...] This is the positive theory of infinity."...

Comment: "That there are infinite classes is so evident that it will scarcely be
denied. Since, however, it is capable of formal proof, it may be as well to prove it. A very simple proof is that suggested in the *Parmenides*, which is as follows."

Comment: The "ontology" of *Principles* is made not only of "physical things"; see page 44: "Whatever may be an object of thought, or may occur in any true or false proposition, or can be counted as one, I call a *term*. I shall use as synonymous with it the words unit, individual and entity. [...] A man, a moment, a number, a class, a relation, a chimaera, or anything else that can be mentioned, is sure to be a term." The "definition" is quite blurerd, but it is clear that for R not only "individuals" exist, but also classes, relations and numbers.

Comment: In *Principia* (1910-13) W&R postulated the *Axiom of Infinity* and in [Introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=WQ7tnG07_68C&pg=PA77) (1919) R asserted it on an "inductive" ground" (see **Ch.VIII**): "It cannot be said to be *certain* that there are in fact any infinite collections in the world. The assumption that there are is what we call the "axiom of infinity" [...] there is no conclusive logical reason for believing it to be true."...

Comment: "At the same time, there is certainly no logical reason  *against* infinite collections, and we are therefore justified, in logic, in investigating the hypothesis that there are such collections."

Comment: Some additonal comments can be found in this related post: [has Dedekind's proof-of-existence-of-infinite-sets-been-analyzed-by-historians ?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/240276/has-dedekinds-proof-of-existence-of-infinite-sets-been-analyzed-by-historians)

Comment: @Masacroso: Overratedness is overrated, as are meta jokes.

Answer (score 6):

You are right that to a mathematician, things are said to 'exist' as long as there is no logical contradiction, which is not the same as 'physical existence'.

But while these two notions are different, the two are nevertheless related: if something is *logically* self-contradictory, then it can't physically exist either.  And that, I believe, was what Russell was getting at.

Indeed, note that Bertrand starts out his first sentence with exactly the notion of a self-contradiction:

> Most of the great ambitious attempts of metaphysicians have proceeded by the attempt to prove that such and such apparent features of the actual world were self-contradictory, and therefore could not be real.

That is, Russell characterizes some of the philosophers as arguing that something was self-contradictory, and therefore impossible to exist, whether logically, mathematically or physically.

Russell then discusses *two* purported contradictions:

> Thus a contradiction emerged between the apparent nature of space and time and the supposed impossibility of infinite collections.

So there are two purported contradictions here:

1. The impossibility of infinity itself. That is, that the very notion of infinity is self-contradictory
2. The impossibility of space and time: space and time being infinitely divisible, thus infinite, and thus (in the light of 1) contradictory

That is, Russell seems to be claiming that both of these self-contradictions were argued for by philosophers, and again: if they are self-contradictory, i.e. *logically* contradictory, then that would imply that they would be physically impossible as well, i.e. there can be no infinities in the real world, and no space and time (at least as we conceive of it) either.

And then Russell of course brings up Cantor to defuse the first contradiction (i.e. that the philosophers were wrong in their arguments against the very notion of infinity) ... and thereby defuse the second contradiction as well.

In other words, all of the arguments really were on the purely logical/mathematical side of things; they just had implications for the nature of reality.

At least, that is my reading of this ...

Comment: +1, I think this is spot-on. I'd add, though, the additional quote from Russell "The impossibility of infinite collections was a mistake. They are not in fact self-contradictory, but only contradictory of certain rather obstinate mental prejudices.", which I think nicely drives the point home. Incidentally, I'd also point out that an important aspect which Russell doesn't touch on here is that not only is Cantor's theory apparently consistent, but also nontrivial - there are interesting questions and theorems! So it's not even "morally contradictory," that is, contradicting worthwhile thought.

Comment: Nope - what note was that?

Comment: Aha! I don't think pinging works for someone not the OP or already in the comment thread. Answering ...

Answer (score 2):

Does the set of positive integers *exist*? In an abstract sense, yes, It's just a conceptual entity. Does it exist as a physical object in the real world? Apparently not, based on our current understanding of physics.

The set of positive integers *could* exist (i.e., be representable) in nature if we could demonstrate the existence of a countable infinity of objects. How do we *know* that no such set of objects exists? Quantum theory asserts a "smallest" unit, that's why. Could that understanding change? Perhaps, who knows?

As far as Russell's apparent acceptance of "infinity", he alludes to the apparent "fact" that on a line, there's always a point strictly between any two points. How does he know that? As I see it, he's blurring real-world existence with conceptual existence.

Russell also asserts that it's not reasonable to believe that the universe is bounded, but that was just a belief on his part. In fact, current theory asserts that the universe is, in fact, bounded.

Similarly, with regard to Russell's assertion that it's reasonable to believe that time is infinite in both directions, again that was just a belief on his part. By current theory, the Big Bang marks the beginning. As far as whether or not there could be an "end" of time, who knows, but I doubt whether any such claim could be proved or disproved.

Comment: But then, what does Russell mean? Russell seems to think that the mathematicians (specifically Cantor) refuted the philosophers on infinity.

Comment: Obviously the positive integers are not going to exist in nature, given that they are abstract objects. The question would then be, are these abstract objects fictional entities (i.e., are we espousing some form of antirealism), or do they exist in some platonic realm.

Comment: The positive integers _could_ exist in nature if we could demonstrate the existence of a countable infinity of objects. How do we _know_ that no such set of objects exists. Quantum theory asserts a "smallest" unit, that's why.

Comment: @quasi But the positive integers are not identical to any collection of objects, especially physical objects, just as the number $2$ is not identical to a scrawling on a piece of paper.

Comment: @quasi how does quantum theory assert a smallest unit, and how does the existence of a smallest unit disprove the existence of countably many objects ? As far as I know, physicists haven't proved yet (and are far from proving it) that the universe is finite, and so there may very well be countably many particles etc. There may even be uncountably many, as far as science nowadays knows.

Comment: @quasi We can't demonstrate a countable infinity in nature because, according to philosophy, there can't really be such a thing as infinity. As many as you have its not infinity. Sure, you can cut something up into infinity pieces; but only if you had an infinite amount of time :)

Comment: @quasi What Isaac says is true. In fact, this is the conclusion of Hilbert's Hotel, the Infinite Book, and the Grim Reaper Paradox (see Alexander Pruss--a brilliant philosopher): that an actual infinite cannot exist. Of course, some will philosophers contend that an actual infinite can in fact exist, but that's only because every position in philosophy is controversial--which is why philosophy is jolly good fun.

Comment: @quasi "Quantum theory asserts a "smallest" unit, that's why." That's missing an important adjective, namely "*observable*" (or "physically meaningful") To my understanding, it is entirely consistent with quantum mechanics that smaller-than-Planck-length entities exist, it's just that they're rendered uninteresting to our existence.

Comment: We can readily observe that (Peano's) Arithmetic exists: just pick up a suitable textbook on Mathematics and look at the right page. Now PA does have the property of containing all natural numbers, by definition. Since we know of something that exists and contains all natural numbers, doesn't that mean that all natural numbers necessarily also exist?

Answer (score 1):

Georg Cantor's realist stance laced with both metaphysics and theology concerning set theory is well-known. What is less well-known is that Bertrand Russell was influenced by Cantor's realist position to a degree somewhat embarrassing for a philosopher.  Thus in his *The principles of mathematics* (1903, not to be confused with the later Latin title lifted from Newton) he makes numerous statements to the effect that "infinite sets really exist" that seem quaint to a scholar today.

What he means by his curious claim is that he considers Cantor to have established an alleged "existence" of infinite sets though it is not clear by dint of which magic wand Cantor may have accomplished such a thing.  Additional details concerning the philosophical errors of both Cantor and Russell can be found in [this publication](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10670-012-9370-y) in the philosophy journal *Erkenntnis*.

"how can he [Cantor] possibly prove such a thing?", indeed.

Comment: "he considers Cantor to have established an alleged "existence" of infinite sets". See *Pinciples* (1903), **Ch.43**, §339, page 362.63.